# to search through the json object and obtain the data

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have my JSON data in a table, I have to search a particular id and display the data of that id.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("data/db.json", function(data){
var dbdata = "";
$.each(data, function(key,value){
            dbdata += '<tr>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.userId + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.completed + '</td>';
            dbdata += '</tr>';
        })
        $('#datainfo').append(dbdata);
    })
})
```

and when I type the id in the input filed it must display the data of that id.

Enter the Id:  
 Search

this is code for displaying the JSON data in a table. I want to search the id so that I get the data of the id.
please provide the function that does search through the JSON object!
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.getJSON("data/db.json", function(data){
var dbdata = "";
$.each(data, function(key,value){
           if ( value.id == "user_search_key"){
            dbdata += '<tr>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.userId + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.id + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.title + '</td>';
            dbdata += '<td>' + value.completed + '</td>';
            dbdata += '</tr>';
              }
        })
        $('#datainfo').append(dbdata);
    })
})
```